# Json path to process json file

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am trying to write Json Path for following json file

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "$d": "abcde"
    },
    "ga": 1,
    "g": "A",
    "report_period": {
        "day": 18,
        "epoch": 1447816080,
        "hour": 3,
        "month": 11,
        "yday": 322,
        "year": 2015
    },
    "sites": [
        {
            "city": "sdf",
            "country": "af",
            "display_name": "af",
            "mcp_id": "af",
            "site_id": "adf",
            "site_name": "affra",
            "state": "afa",
            "type": "af"
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

I am testing my json path in 
http://www.jsonquerytool.com/ 
So my problem is how can i write json path to extract value for $d,report_period etc.
I have tried many json path.Like to extract $d, i have written something like '._id.$d' but it is not working .I have checked many sites but none of them have given how to acess json value which starts with [ .

Answer (score 0):

The object is contained within a list. First, you need to access the first element of the array, so it should be something like `nameOfVariable[0]._id.$d`

Comment: what would be the name of the base variable??.Would you have checked that this path is working in  http://www.jsonquerytool.com/  ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your query with:
`$.[0]`
Because your JSON object data is stored within a root array.

Example for report period would be:

`$.[0].report_period`

Example for $d would be:

`$.[0]._id.$d`

I find https://jsonpath.com to be a better tool for testing